# The distribution of a random vector $(X,Y)$ is given by a table

Tags: probability

The distribution of a random vector $(X,Y)$ is given by a table:

\begin{bmatrix}
X/Y &-1  & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & \frac{1}{10} & 0 & \frac{4}{10}\\ 
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{10} & 0\\ 
2 & \frac{2}{10} & 0 & \frac{2}{10}
\end{bmatrix}

**a)** Find the distribution of a random variable $X$

**b)** Calculate the covariance of random variables $X$,$Y$

**c)** Are random variables $X$ i $Y$ independent?

My answers:

**a)**

$P(X=0)=\frac{5}{10}$

$P(X=1)=\frac{1}{10}$

$P(X=2)=\frac{4}{10}$

**b)**

$EX= (0\cdot\frac{1}{10})+(0\cdot 0)+(0\cdot\frac{4}{10})+(1\cdot0)+(1\cdot\frac{1}{10})+(1\cdot 0)+(2\cdot \frac{2}{10})+(2\cdot 0)+(2\cdot \frac{2}{10})=\frac{9}{10}$

$EY= -\frac{1}{10}-\frac{2}{10}+\frac{4}{10}+\frac{2}{10}=\frac{3}{10}$

$
EXY= (2 \cdot -1 \cdot \frac{2}{10})+(2 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{2}{10})=-\frac{4}{10}+\frac{4}{10}=0$

$EXEY= \frac{9}{10} \cdot \frac{3}{10} = \frac{27}{100}$

$Cov(X,Y)= 0-\frac{27}{100}=-\frac{27}{100}$

**c)** The product of the boundary values ​​is not equal to
$\frac{1}{10} \neq \frac{5}{10} \cdot \frac{3}{10}$
So they are dependent

I wrote a program that calculates these values:
[image: Text]

So far it only confirms that I didn't do any billing errors, can anyone check if logic behind calculations is correct? This way I could check future tasks like this by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(a)$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X=0) &= \mathbb P(X=0,Y=-1) + \mathbb P(X=0,Y=0) + \mathbb P(X=0,Y=1) \\
&= \frac1{10}+0+\frac25 = \frac12\\
\mathbb P(X=1) &= \mathbb P(X=1,Y=-1) + \mathbb P(X=1,Y=0) + \mathbb P(X=1,Y=1) \\
&= 0+\frac1{10}+0 = \frac1{10}\\
\mathbb P(X=2) &= \mathbb P(X=2,Y=-1) + \mathbb P(X=2,Y=0) + \mathbb P(X=2,Y=1) \\
&= \frac15+0+\frac15 = \frac25.
\end{align}

For $(b)$ we compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= 0\cdot\mathbb P(X=0)+1\cdot\mathbb P(X=1)+2\cdot\mathbb P(X=2)\\
&= \frac1{10} + \frac45\\
&=\frac9{10}
\end{align}
We can compute the marginal distribution of $Y$ as we did for $X$ and hence compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y] &= 0\cdot\mathbb P(Y=0)+1\cdot\mathbb P(Y=1)+2\cdot\mathbb P(Y=2)\\
&= -\frac3{10}+\frac35\\
&= \frac3{10}.
\end{align}
We then compute $\mathbb E[XY]$ by
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[XY] &= \sum_{i=0}^2\sum_{j=-1}^1 i\cdot j\cdot\mathbb P(X=i,Y=j)\\
&= -2\cdot\frac15 +2\cdot\frac15 = 0,
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y) &= \mathbb E[XY] - \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y]\\
&= 0 - \frac9{10}\cdot\frac3{10} = -\frac{27}{100}.
\end{align}

Since $\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)\ne0$, we conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, how would you calculate $P(X,Y)$ based on this table? Sum of boundary values?

Comment: What do you mean by "$P(X,Y)$"?

Comment: Nevermind, friend from studies explained it to me.
I didn't know what the calculations should be for $P(X,Y)$, he gave me this formula: $P(X,Y)=\frac{cov(x,y)}{EX \cdot EY}$. Thanks for help

Comment: What is "$P(X,Y)$" supposed to be? i.e. is there a name for this notation? Generally a capital $P$ refers to a probability, but what you have written looks like an incorrect form of the correlation of $X$ and $Y$: $$\rho(X,Y) := \frac{\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}(X)}\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}(Y)}}.$$ Considering that your expression would not be defined if $X$ or $Y$ had mean zero, and it is one I have never seen in several years of studying probability, I believe your friend was in error.